# Using generic type declarations in Abstract Java class

Tags: java, generics

I have the following

```
public abstract class BaseImpl<T>{
  public T getObject();
}
```

Now I want to extend the class like this

```
public class PersonImpl{
  //Works
  public Object getObject(){}
  //But I would like it to be like this
  public Person getObject(){}
}
```

I am not very good with generics but is this possible? Is there a better pattern here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the generic version of `BaseImpl`, supplying the type you want:

```
public class PersonImpl extends BaseImpl<Person> {
```

Comment: ... and the IDE takes care of the rest.

Comment: Too bad I am using vi w/o c tags ;-) P.S. is this a duplicate?